# MicrobiomeTest::generate_alpha_trend_test_long() not recognising rownames and columns

Tags: r, dataformat, longitudinal

Good morning everyone,
I am trying to use MicrobiomeTest to perform a longitudinal analysis on a microbial community. It worked all fine at the beginning, but after I used a different dataset, the functions are providing the error listed below.

```
Error in update_data_obj_count(data.obj, rarefied_otu_tab) : 
 The provided count table must have row and column names.
```

For privacy policy I cannot provide the original dataset used. However, I can confirm that the creation of the Microbiome object was successful without errors, which mean the correct match between the column and row names was found.

It's a long shot, but I hope someone can help with this or providing advice on possible alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after I found out that the dataset contained some 0 columns. Removing the columns resulted in no error. While the code worked, I am now investigating the best way to deal with the 0 columns.